# How to deny an application network access in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, ubuntu

In Ubuntu, is there any way to deny an application to access network?

I mean ,I have an application ,say app1,

I want to deny it from access the network for some security reason,
but for other applications ,I still want to enable them to access the network

in Windows, there are many tools can do it,for example ,comodo firewall,zonealarm...
but in Ubuntu I wonder if there're any tools

Comment: This sounds like an OS question rather than a programming question.  You might have better luck moving this over to [superuser](http://superuser.com) which is meant for questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SELINUX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SELinux) if you want that kind of granularity on your security settings. It's neither straightforward nor simple. [Here's a blog entry with some examples that might help](http://securityblog.org/brindle/2007/05/28/secure-networking-with-selinux/).